# how to map/pull column in 1 sheet based on another to repeating values in excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have excel sheet with repeating ids

```
id      jun19    
1       3
2       2
3       7
1       3
2       2
3       7
1       3
2       2
3       7
```

i want to append another column 'jul19' from another sheet.
that jul19 sheet has all and even more ids:

```
id     jul19
1       4
2       6
3       45
4       7
5       9
```

it should take only those that have the id and pull values from column 'jul19'.

the end result is this:

```
id      jun19     jul19
    1       3       4
    2       2       6
    3       7       45
    1       3       4
    2       2       6
    3       7       45
    1       3       4
    2       2       6
    3       7       45
```

how to do this? how to pull corresponding values from column "jul19" based on the id?

I tried to do this in pandas, but failed.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

or what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table1 is in A1:B10, table2 is in D1:E6, & table3 is in G1:I10. put :

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(G2,D:D,0)) in I2
```

and drag downwards. ref : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

Hope it helps. ( :